# BSNL Penta TPad 701C Android ICS - Play store closes immediately after opening.

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, updates

When I got the tablet, new version of play store was pre-installed and was working fine. Initially my 3G dongle was not connecting to Internet. After complaining to customer care, I was provided a firmware with which I updated my tablet. Then onwards, I could connect to Internet but Play store was gone. I managed to download it and installed it on tablet but now it opens and closes without any error message.

I have already tried:

1. Re installing the given ROM
2. Done factory reset
3. Tried to install different versions (v3.5.19, v3.7.16, etc) of Play Store app.

None of the above solved the probelm. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to install appropriate version of GApps? If I were you, I will try installing gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip from http://goo.im/gapps.

Comment: @Narayanan I have no idea what GApps is .... If you can explain me what it is  brother

Comment: Please give me proper link to download I don't know which one to select .....  and I hope this thing will not burst my tablet ....:P

Comment: I think gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip is fine for me

Comment: Try this Link http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2012/12/bsnl-701c-penta-tablet-3gplay-store-not.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ROM that BSNL customer care provided might not have GApps installed. You can download a relevant version of GApps from [goo.im/gapps](http://goo.im/gapps).  Based on the information you had provided, you can use [gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-ics-20120429-signed.zip).

Download that ZIP file and place it in your SD card. Install [ROMManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&feature=search_result) from [their](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) site. Once installed, choose install ZIP option and select the ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for the solution I will try. Is there any other method or app to download apps from play store ???

Comment: Check out http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps to know about GApps. In short, they are the apps developed by Google. Play Store, Google Maps, Google search, YouTube, Street View, Voice search etc are few. Though Android is an open source and free to distribute, GApps are not. Hence at times you may have to download and install them separately.